# Get AWS Beanstalk to run Rails app from subfolder as opposed to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a repo with the folder structure as such

```
 root_of_repo
   -app
   -some_gem
   -some_gem
```

Within the `app` folder is where my Rails app lives. I would like for beanstalk to deploy the rails app from within this folder. However, it keeps trying to deploy the Rails app from the root. How would I tell beanstalk to first navigate into the app folder then continue running the necessary rails actions (bundle, rails s, etc).

Answer (score 1):

beanstalk is very sensitive to structure as its deployment process is mostly a bunch of shell scripts wrapped together. therefore it won't bend to your new structure.
a couple of options here:
1. adapt to the standard structure, which is also recommended by rails. don't nest "app" folders.
2. create a pre-deploy script (.ebextension) that copies your folder to the right place.